# When I select an object, it does not show it as selected

Tags: selection-tools

When I select an object, it does not show it as selected, same for faces and vertices. I tried updating blender to the latest version, but it seems that the problem is only in the project because it doesn't happen on other ones. Would anybody know how to fix it ? (in the picture, you can see on the right panel that a part is selected but it ain't shown)[image: my problem]

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled the *Show Overlays* option (or shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>):

[image]